# Composer install not including hiddeninput.exe

Tags: git, cmd, composer-php

It would appear that hiddeninput.exe is missing from my composer installation.
I have never come across this, and I am hoping somebody can help put some sense behind this.
Recently I got a new machine and after installing everything as normal (Xampp, Composer etc) I started noticing this issue.

How the issue came about: I cloned a repository with git (which is private) and when I run composer update, I get the following error:

```
composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Cloning failed using an ssh key for authentication, enter your GitHub credentials to access private repos
Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+DESKTOP-LOIEB7C+2020-10-30+1319
to retrieve a token. It will be stored in "C:/Users/colin/AppData/Roaming/Composer/auth.json" for future use by Composer.
Token (hidden):

  [ErrorException]
  copy(phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/../Resources/bin/hiddeninput.exe): failed to op
  en stream: phar error: "vendor/symfony/console/Resources/bin/hiddeninput.exe" is not a file in phar "C:/composer/co
  mposer.phar"


update [--with WITH] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-install] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [-w|--with-dependencies] [-W|--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]…
```

The top part, advising me I need a key, i'm expecting this message. At this point I used to get the chance to enter my key however it would appear that the software that allows that input "Hiddeninput.exe" is missing from the .phar file for my composer installation.

I have uninstalled composer and reinstalled using both developer mode and the simple option but I am getting nowhere.

Is there a reason for this, am I missing something incredibly obvious here?

Using the most recent version of composer
Xampp installation
PHP 7.2.34

Comment: Can you share more details? As far as I see, the file exists in the repository. Have you checked whether any antivirus mechanism is in place, such that the file access is blocked?

Comment: problem is : accessing a private repo (i.e. github) on windows with composer 2.x ... there seems to be a missing file for hidden-inputs in the composer.phar

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem,
I solve it doing a "composer selfupdate"

Answer (score 0):

it may be deleted by the antivirus program, such as windows defender.

here : [take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAjwk.png)

You may try disable the antivirus or make your project folder as excluded list.